# dict1 is the subset of dict2 when dict2 contains same key and value that dict1 has

Tags: python-3.x

example:
if a = dict(a=1,b=2) b = dict(a=1,b=2, c=3)
dict1 is the subset of dict2 when dict2 contains same key and value that dict1 has

what is the simplest way to do it?

This is what i have so far. is there any other method to return a bool that determine whether dict1 is subset of dict2?

```
condition = True
for a, b in dict1.items():
    if dict2[a] = b:
        condition = False
return condition
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to take advantage of the simplicity of the set set. You must convert the dicts to sets of tuples. For that, you must firstly convert the dicts to lists of tuples, and then create the sets. After that, you'll be able to use the method set.issubset:

```
def issubset(dict1, dict2):
    # dict -> list
    list1 = list(dict1.items())
    list2 = list(dict2.items())

    # list -> set
    set1 = set(list1)
    set2 = set(list2)

    return set1.issubset(set2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ask `all(x in b and a[x]==b[x] for x in a)` if subdict means same keys associated with same values. It will stop at the first difference.